# How to create a user and password while launching AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

Azure allows one to create the user and password during the creation of a virtual machine which can later be used for SSH into that VM.

How to create a user and password during `run instance` in AWS using Java SDK which can be used for SSH.

Currently I laucnh Vm as

```
  runInstancesRequest
                    .withTagSpecifications(tagSpecification)
                    .withImageId(ec2Configuration.getImageId())
                    .withInstanceType(ec2Configuration.getInstanceType())
                    .withMinCount(ec2Configuration.getMincount())
                    .withMaxCount(ec2Configuration.getMaxcount())
                    .withKeyName(ec2Configuration.getKeyPairName())
                    .withSecurityGroupIds(Arrays.asList(ec2Configuration.getSgId()));
                    .withMonitoring(true);
         
          
                RunInstancesResult result = amazonEC2Client.runInstances(
                        runInstancesRequest);
```

I want to add something like this

```
    runInstancesRequest
                    .withTagSpecifications(tagSpecification)
                    .withImageId(ec2Configuration.getImageId())
                    .withInstanceType(ec2Configuration.getInstanceType())
                    .withMinCount(ec2Configuration.getMincount())
                    .withMaxCount(ec2Configuration.getMaxcount())
                    .withKeyName(ec2Configuration.getKeyPairName())
                    .withSecurityGroupIds(Arrays.asList(ec2Configuration.getSgId()));
                    .withMonitoring(true)


                    .withUserName("newUser")
                    .withPassword("d@mnHardPassw0rd");
         
          
                RunInstancesResult result = amazonEC2Client.runInstances(
                        runInstancesRequest);
```

I know AWS has default usernames and passwords based on the AMI but I want to make my own custom username and password while launching the VM.

**Edit**

Also, How to SSH to a Windows a instance? Is the RDP only option? How can I connect via the key pair and SSH? How to get it's administrator password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it using UserData:

```
RunInstancesRequest.withUserData(String userData)
```

and the user data can be found in the URL below

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-user-account-cloud-init-user-data/

Comment: Also, does it apply for windows Instance too? How can I ssh to Windows instance. Please see the Edit.

Comment: In the answer above, do we need to install `cloud-init` on the instance or is it  preinstalled. I want to create the user while launching the instance.

Comment: these commands are also executed in the user data !, I suggest you read what is the user data, you can install anything using user data which will be executed while launching the instance https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html